# pairwise_t_test not returning statistic

Tags: r, rstatix

```
pwc <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  pairwise_t_test(
    value ~ variable1, paired = TRUE,
    p.adjust.method = "bonferroni", detailed = TRUE
  )
```

pwc does include statistic or dfs. This only happens when I combine group_by and pairwise_t_test. Why is that?

This only happens when I combine group_by and pairwise_t_test. Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(df)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: Your question fits here https://stats.stackexchange.com/ better. You'll probably get an answer quicker.